# how can i change none and write the value?

Tags: python-3.x, variables, nltk

this code take all the pos_tag of the sentence and count the score of each word

```
def sentence_score(sentence_tokens, previous_token, acum_score):    
  if not sentence_tokens:
     return acum_score
  else:

    current_token = sentence_tokens[0]
    tags = current_token[2]
    token_score = sum([value(tag) for tag in tags])
    if previous_token is not None:
        previous_tags = previous_token[2]
        #print('token1', previous_tags)
        if 'inc' in previous_tags:
            token_score += 1.0
        elif 'dec' in previous_tags:
            token_score -= 1.0
        elif 'inv' in previous_tags:
            token_score -= 2
  return sentence_score(sentence_tokens[1:], current_token, acum_score + token_score)
```

i want to change None for write your value in txt

```
def sentiment_score(text):
 return sum([sentence_score(sentence, None,0.0) for sentence in text])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to `return token_score`. When any function ends without executing the explicit `return` command, the implicit `return None` is used.

**(Update)**

```
def sentence_score(sentence_tokens, previous_token, acum_score):    
    if not sentence_tokens:
        return acum_score
    else:
        current_token = sentence_tokens[0]
        tags = current_token[2]
        token_score = sum([value(tag) for tag in tags])
        if previous_token is not None:
            previous_tags = previous_token[2]
            #print('token1', previous_tags)
            if 'inc' in previous_tags:
                token_score += 1.0
            elif 'dec' in previous_tags:
                token_score -= 1.0
            elif 'inv' in previous_tags:
                token_score -= 2
        return token_score
```

Comment: return sentence_score(sentence_tokens[1:], current_token, acum_score + token_score) this is the return but i can't write the output

Comment: By adding the last line, you are calling the `sentence_score()` function recursively. I guess it ends with some error, because you pass variables that do not exist, yet. I do not know the problem being solved, but you probably want to return `token_score` at the end of the `else` branch, without the last return `sentence_score()` -- unless you need recursion. If you need to use recursion, the recursive call must be done conditionally.

Comment: See the update. Notice that the last `return` belongs to the `else` branch. Is it what you want? Probably not. You proably want to return `token_score` and `accum_score` in both return commands, and then you want to call it in a loop. Or you need a recursive solution, but you have to describe the problem being solved a bit better.